# How to get class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hey, I am trying to get the class names dynamically for the script below.

I have different class names that are created through PHP so need to get them using jQuery dynamically.

As you can see below, there seems to be 2 areas where I need to get the class name. At the moment it is hard coded (the classes are named 'result'):

1) var new_content = $('**#hiddenresult div.result**:eq('+page_index+')').clone();

2) var num_entries = $('**#hiddenresult div.result**').length;

so, I'd like jquery to get the class name instead of me just hard coding it in as seen below.

The jQuery file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
        var new_content = $('#hiddenresult div.result:eq('+page_index+')').clone();
        $('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
        return false;
    }

    /** 
     * Callback function for the AJAX content loader.
     */
    function initPagination() {
        var num_entries = $('#hiddenresult div.result').length;
        // Create pagination element
        $("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, {
            num_edge_entries: 2,
            num_display_entries: 8,
            callback: pageselectCallback,
            items_per_page:1
        });
     }

    // Load HTML snippet with AJAX and insert it into the Hiddenresult element
    // When the HTML has loaded, call initPagination to paginate the elements        
    $(document).ready(function(){      
        initPagination();
    });
</script>
```

Any help on implementing a solution would be great. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample of your HTML markups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want your code to work regardless of the class that is given to the divs. (but some class will be given)

If so use

```
var new_content = $('#hiddenresult div[class]:eq('+page_index+')').clone();
```

and

```
var num_entries = $('#hiddenresult div[class]').length;
```

which means find any div under #hiddenresult that has a class attribute defined (regardless of the actual class name..)

Comment: On a related note, I'd recommend using the `.eq(page_index)` function instead of the `:eq` selector. Explanation on my blog here: http://spadgos.com/?p=51

Answer (score 0):

You can get the contents of the class attribute as a string like this:
`$("#hiddenresult div").attr("class");`
Note: this may not work for you if your element has multiple classes assigned to it.

You can also use this:
`$("#hiddenresult div").hasClass("result");`
To check if an element has a specific class.